# How do I use the timeout flag in gcloud run deploy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to deploy a node app to cloud run using the reference https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy. The build takes around 12 mins so I am including the timeout flag mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--timeout.

My command looks like this:

```
gcloud run deploy my-node-project --timeout 900 --source .
```

My build still times out after 10 minutes though. How do I adjust it to give me the 12 minutes I need?

Comment: You're interested in revising the build time of the container. The `--timeout` flag is the execution timeout of the running process. i.e. different timeouts. I assume you're using `--source` too and suspect you'll need to disentangle the container image build from deployment.

Comment: If you use Cloud Build directly (e.g. `gcloud builds submit`), you can include a [`--timeout`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit#--timeout) flag on `build.yaml` [timeout](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#timeout_2) value to increase the build (!) timeout as you need. Cloud Build will produce your artifact and you can then use `gcloud run deploy --image...` to deploy it. More complex but more configurable too.

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin this was the approach I was trying to avoid.. Looks like I’m going to have to bite the bullet and do things the ‘proper’ way :)

Comment: Unless someone else has a better idea, I think you will need to decompose the process into the 2 distinct steps. It's no more "proper" than what you were doing since `gcloud run deploy --source` decoomposes to `gcloud builds submit` and `gcloud run deploy` effectively anyway. You will get more flexibility.